# dockerを利用したyolov3のmake エラーについて

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, 深層学習

Dockerfileに

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN pip3 install keras tensorflow-gpu
```

このように記載してコンテナを立てて

```
git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet
cd darknet
vim #GPU=1に変更
make
```

すると

```
In file included from ./src/utils.h:5:0,
    from ./src/gemm.c:2:
include/darknet.h:14:30: fatal error: cuda_runtime.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed
make: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1`
```

のようなエラーがでます。

おそらくdarknetのMakefile(下記)`COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include`部分で指定しているincludeフォルダがないからではないかと思っています。

```
ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
    COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/
    CFLAGS+= -DGPU
    LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif
```

質問はdockerでyoloをGPU=1にしてmakeするにはどのようにMakefileを設定すればよいのでしょうか。またCOMMON+=、CFLAGS+=、LDFLAGS+=はそれぞれ何を設定しているのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このページ https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA にあるように，`runtime`コンテナには静的ライブラリなどは入っておらず，CUDAを使用するアプリケーションをビルドするには`devel`コンテナを使用する必要があります．

ですから，Dockerfileの

`FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04`を
`FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04`

とすればビルドできるようになります．

Answer (score 0):

ご自分でも指摘しておられる”COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include”の部分ですが、cudaをインストールしたときにパスがcudaで登録されていない場合があります。ですのでcuda9のパスが”cuda-9.0”になっている可能性があります（要確認）。
この場合は”COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include”のパスにすればmakeが通るはずです。

Comment: ”COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include”のパスにしてもmakeは通りませんでした。上記のdocker imageを利用すると/usr/local/cuda-9.0/、/usr/local/cuda/のどちらにもincludeがありませんでした。

Comment: 端末にて一度$cd をしてユーザーまで戻り、$ nano .bashrcをしてcudaのパスを確認してみてください。もしくは/usr/local/cuda/includeの存在を確認してください。もしかしたらなぜか入らなかった可能性もあります。